# Split a list of dictionaries into multiple chunks

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

I have this one list

```
list_dict = [
 {'id': 1},
 {'item': 'apple'},
 {'id': 2},
 {'item': 'pear'},
 {'id': 1},
 {'item': 'peach'},
 {'id': 2},
 {'item': 'kiwi'},
 {'id': 3},
 {'item': 'banana'},
 {'id': 4},
 {'item': 'mango'},
 {'id': 1},
 {'item': 'watermelon'},
 {'id': 2},
 {'item': 'plum'},
 {'id': 3},
 {'item': 'grapes'}]
```

and I want to split like this (start to make sublist when "id" is 1)

```
result = [
 [{'id': 1},
  {'item': 'apple'},
  {'id': 2},
  {'item': 'pear'}],
 [{'id': 1},
  {'item': 'peach'},
  {'id': 2},
  {'item': 'kiwi'},
  {'id': 3},
  {'item': 'banana'},
  {'id': 4},
  {'item': 'mango'}],
 [{'id': 1},
  {'item': 'watermelon'},
  {'id': 2},
  {'item': 'plum'},
  {'id': 3},
  {'item': 'grapes'}]]
```

Comment: Cool. What did you try? Where did you fail? What is your problem?

Comment: IMHO the question is crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Some nested for loop will work

```py
list_dict = [{"id":1},{"item":"apple"},{"id":2},{"item":"pear"},{"id":1},{"item":"peach"},{"id":2},{"item":"kiwi"},{"id":3},{"item":"banana"},{"id":4},{"item":"mango"},{"id":1},{"item":"watermelon"},{"id":2},{"item":"plum"},{"id":3},{"item":"grapes"}]

output = []
temp = []
for i in list_dict:
  if i.get('id', -1) == 1 and temp:
    output.append(temp.copy())
    temp.clear()
    temp.append(i)
  else:
    temp.append(i)

output.append(temp.copy())

print(output)
#[[{'id': 1}, {'item': 'apple'}, {'id': 2}, {'item': 'pear'}], [{'id': 1}, {'item': 'peach'}, {'id': 2}, {'item': 'kiwi'}, {'id': 3}, {'item': 'banana'}, {'id': 4}, {'item': 'mango'}], [{'id': 1}, {'item': 'watermelon'}, {'id': 2}, {'item': 'plum'}, {'id': 3}, {'item': 'grapes'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```py
main_list = []
current_list = []
for el in list_dict:
    if el.get("id", 0) == 1:
        if current_list:
            main_list.append(current_list)
        current_list = [el]
    else:
        current_list.append(el)

if current_list:
    main_list.append(current_list)
    
print(main_list)
```